# C language. Logic error: The left operand of '-' is a garbage value

Tags: objective-c, c

I have the following code, but in this line of code I have warning `x[i] = (rhs[i] - x[i - 1]) / b;`, compiler is telling me that rhs[i] is a garbage value. Why it's happend? And how to remove this warning?

```
double* getFirstControlPoints(double* rhs, const int n) {
    double *x;
    x = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double *tmp; // Temp workspace.
    tmp = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    double b = 2.0;
    x[0] = rhs[0] / b;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) // Decomposition and forward substitution.
    {
        tmp[i] = 1 / b;
        b = (i < n - 1 ? 4.0 : 3.5) - tmp[i];
        x[i] = (rhs[i] - x[i - 1]) / b; //The left operand of '-' is a garbage value
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        x[n - i - 1] -= tmp[n - i] * x[n - i]; // Backsubstitution.
    }
    free(tmp);
    return x;
}
```

[image]

[image]

All compiler warnings and calling `getFirstControlPoints` you may see on screenshots.

Comment: I have removed the `objective-c` tag from this question because this is a pure `C` question.

Comment: I can't see anything to suggest that it would be garbage in the function. How are you calling it? (although I've no idea if that would affect anything)

Comment: gcc doesn't give any error or warning, as long as you compile in C99 or C++ mode. Maybe the error is coming from somewhere else? Can you post the exact error message? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Re-added, because now there's objective C as well.

Comment: As you can see I add all code where I calling getFirstControlPoints(). So as you I understand all arrays are initialised.

Comment: The arrays might be correctly allocated, but it looks like they're not fully filled with data. Check thoroughly if you are assigning all elements. _edit_: Ok, it _looks_ like you're initializing it completely...

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Fair enough.

Comment: To silence the code analyzer, you could always use `calloc(n, sizeof(double)`, but that is only a workaround...

Comment: Is this at runtime or compile time? What compiler? What is the exact warning including warning number?

Comment: This is at compiler time. Apple LLVM 4.0

Comment: @onitake the output is from the clang static analyser, not the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a check to make sure you have at least **4** points in the `points` array because this loop (line 333):

```
for (NSInteger i = 1 ; i < n - 1 ; ++i) {
    // initialisation stuff
}
```

will not execute at all for n = 0, 1, 2.

Assume that `points` has 3 objects in it, At line 311 you set n to the count - 1 i.e. `n == 2`

Then the loop condition is `i < 2 - 1` i.e. `i < 1`.

I think you need the loop condition to be `i < n`

Answer (score 0):

if points.count is 0 or 1 you are facing some problems, because then, n is -1 or 0, and you access rhs[n-1]; and you malloc n* bytes;

maybe that can be the problem. that you put some rangechecks int o the code?

Comment: I add check `if (points.count > 1) {//add code from - (void)calculateCurvePointsForPoints:(NSArray *)points function}`, but nothing changed. But you right this check need to add.

Comment: Can you update the code and screenshots accordingly? That warning means the value may be uninitialized, but it's hard to figure out why the preprocessor thinks so without the exact code.